# How can i order by date column of LEFT JOINED table?

Tags: mysql, database

How can i order my list by a date column of the JOINED table? My Query is like this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
t.*, c.*
FROM table t
LEFT JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.column1 = t.column2
WHERE t.column3 IS NULL 
GROUP BY DATE(t.date) 
ORDER BY DATE(t1.date) DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

t1.date is a datetime value and can also be null sometimes, but i dont think that should actually affect the order right? t1.date is a datetime column and should be ordered by date without time portion...

My retrieved results however are not ordered by t1.date in DESC order. What am i missing?

***Update:
i have replaced the last part of my query like this:
...

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN t1.date IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, DATE(t1.date), TIME(t1.date) ASC
```

Now its seems to be working fine. please correct me if i am mistaking.

Comment: What *are* they ordered by?

Comment: t1.date is a datetime column and it should be ordered by 
ORDER BY date...

Comment: I'm not asking what it *should* be ordered by. I'm asking what it appears to be sorted by. Are there nulls at the top or bottom? We need some sample data. I recommend creating a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: ok let me create a sample fiddle,

Comment: You didn't include results from t1 in your query.  More than likely, the results are ordered by t1.date, but you can't tell because you can't see that column.

Comment: i am not familiar with this mysql fiddle and cannot get it to work but i think i found the right answer to my question. See edit

Comment: Your new order by makes sense. It will stick all of your NULL `t1.date` records at the bottom and all of your non-NULL `t1.date` values at the top. Then, within those two groups, it will order by date, then by time.

Comment: Performance benefits aside, in the adbsence of any aggregating functions, GROUP BY should be avoided. Ordinarily DISTINCT would be used instead, but on a well-formed schema, and where all columns are selected, this is clearly meaningless.